# Angular.js routing: Previous and Next pager

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm new to Angular.js, so I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this, and I'm surprised there isn't a bunch of tutorials that cover this question.

(There are plenty that cover pagination of a long list of results - but my problem seems quite different.)

I have successfully implemented routes for a number of pages within my "single page application" / website. These pages have a natural order, so I am trying to implement Previous and Next buttons (or links) in the header, so that the Next button cycles through Home > Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3 > Home, and the previous button goes backwards from Home > Page 3 > Page 2 > Page 1 > Home.

Having read some relevant-ish articles, tutorials, examples, and StackOverflow Q&As I've tried a few methods that I thought might work, but the Prev / Next buttons do not dynamically update as intended when the route / ng-view changes.

i.e. in my simplified code below (with Home, About and Contact pages), the targets of the Previous / Next buttons and their respective functions `nextPage()` and `prevPage()` always relate to the "Home" page's previous and next pages, even when another page has been navigated to.

### index.html (the important bits)

```
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">

      <button class="btn" ng-click="prevPage()">Previous</button>

      <button class="btn" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="main">
    <div ng-view></div> 
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // Page routes
        .when('/', { templateUrl : 'pages/home.html', controller  : 'mainController' })
        .when('/about', { templateUrl : 'pages/about.html', controller  : 'aboutController' })
        .when('/contact', { templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html', controller  : 'contactController' })
        .otherwise( {redirectTo:'/'} );
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/about'); };
    $scope.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/contact'); };
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/contact'); };
    $scope.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/'); };
});

app.controller('contactController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/contact'); };
    $scope.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/'); };
});
```

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKOb1cN4hmBeVOXLXEDs?p=preview) (it's based based on [this one](http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/preview)).

What is the best way of achieving this?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the buttons are bound to functions on the `mainController`, which are not the ones being changed when the `/about` and `/contact` routes are being shown.

You could add another `homeController` for the `/` route and have all the three route controllers change the `mainController`'s `nextPage` and `prevPage` functions appropriately.

Like:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // Page routes
        .when('/', { templateUrl : 'pages/home.html', controller  : 'homeController' })
        .when('/about', { templateUrl : 'pages/about.html', controller  : 'aboutController' })
        .when('/contact', { templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html', controller  : 'contactController' })
        .otherwise( {redirectTo:'/'} );
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/about'); };
  $scope.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/contact'); };
});

app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$parent.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/about'); };
  $scope.$parent.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/contact'); };
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$parent.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/contact'); };
  $scope.$parent.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/'); };
});

app.controller('contactController', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$parent.nextPage = function() { $location.path('/'); };
  $scope.$parent.prevPage = function() { $location.path('/about'); };
});
```

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Q2IIn?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it behaves like this, is because the scope object you define in your controllers, is only inside the `ng-view`, and outside of it, the scope is bound to the main controller (since you passed it in in the `ng-controller`).

you can see it here http://plnkr.co/edit/sh5JcJs82c7uIiVg6Skg?p=preview
where the `hello` variable, is different when it's outside the `ng-view`.

My sulotion is you should use the `$rootScope`, here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/krs7mzcIVktXxFPvG44R?p=preview

(btw, another issue, you did in the contact controller wrong, and I fixed it).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This example work with one controller for router

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', { templateUrl : 'pages/home.html', controller  : 'mainController' })
    .when('/about', { templateUrl : 'pages/about.html', controller  : 'mainController' })
    .when('/contact', { templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html', controller  : 'mainController' })
    .otherwise( {redirectTo:'/home'} );
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
     $scope.nextPage = function() { 
         if(!$rootScope.currentPage || $rootScope.currentPage == 0){
            $rootScope.currentPage = 1;
            $location.path('/about'); 
         }else if($rootScope.currentPage == 1){
            $rootScope.currentPage = 2;
            $location.path('/contact'); 
         }
         else if($rootScope.currentPage == 2){
            $rootScope.currentPage = 0;
            $location.path('/home'); 
         }
     }

     $scope.prevPage = function() { 
         if(!$rootScope.currentPage || $rootScope.currentPage == 0){
            $rootScope.currentPage = 2;
            $location.path('/contact'); 
         }else if($rootScope.currentPage == 1){
            $rootScope.currentPage = 0;
            $location.path('/home'); 
         }else{
            $rootScope.currentPage = 1;
            $location.path('/about'); 
         }
      };
});
```